# How to close only single dialog on ESC key in WPF/WinForms?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, esc-key

I have a WPF form. It handles the `KeyUp` event and if the released key was Escape, it closes itself.

Also this form has a button to show some Windows Form as a dialog. It does handle the Escape key in the same way.

What happens is that when I press Escape when in the child dialog, both windows close. I expect only the child Windows Forms window to close in this case.

What's the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest option for **WPF** is set the button property `IsCancel` to `true`. Then if you press `ESC` the form would be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the KeyUp event's handled property equal to true:

```
private void myDialogForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```